# PHP - include() or require() with relative paths won't work on windows, even when appending __DIR__

Tags: php, include, relative-path, require

I was reading here about problems in PHP when using include() or required() with relative paths and all the solutions I saw was to append **DIR**

I'm currently working on Windows, and even though the error message displays the current value of **DIR**, then the relative path seems to be added as a string, rather than going one level up, for example:

```
include(__DIR__ . "..\\another_folder\\file_2.php");
```

produces the following error:
    Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\main_folder..\another_folder\file_2.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add the `\` after the directory name:

```
include(__DIR__ . "\\..\\another_folder\\file_2.php");
```

This will make the path be

> C:\xampp\htdocs\main_folder\..\another_folder\file_2.php

instead of

> C:\xampp\htdocs\main_folder..\another_folder\file_2.php

Also, for portability, it is advisable to use `/` instead of `\`, which works on all platforms, including Windows:

```
include(__DIR__ . "/../another_folder/file_2.php");
```

Comment: Thank you for both tips! I was wondering about portability as well... 

Cheers man!

Comment: `__DIR__  . '../dir'` fixed the bug behavior on Windows 10)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use backslashes in paths in PHP, use regular forward slashes (`/`) everywhere. PHP will translate to the appropriate OS-specific directory separators for you automatically.

That being said, look at the error message in detail:

```
 ... lude(C:\xampp\htdocs\main_folder..\another_folder\file_2.php) [func...
                                     ^--- missing a slash here
```

Comment: Thank you!, I thought the last slash was not important as the idea was to go up one folder and then down again to 'another_folder'. Working now!